# Merge 2 databases into another one without duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have a question I want to merge 2 databases into another one but the problem is there are duplicate rows. So how can I merge the 2 databases into another one without duplicate records? I hope someone can help me.

### Database 1

### Name | Number | Code

Demo | 0293   | 827

### Test | 0482   | 923

### Database 2

### Name | Number | Code

Lol  | 0223   | 182
Stack| 1923   | 829
Demo | 0293   | 827

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This should really be done with a unique key and `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. If not willing to do that, the following would also work:*

Assuming the tables are identical and that you only want to exclude a row when ALL columns  are the same as a row in the target table.

```
INSERT into Table1 
 SELECT * from Table2 
 WHERE concat(Name,'|',Number,'|',Code) not in (
  SELECT concat(Name,'|',Number,'|',Code) 
  FROM Table1
 )
```

Comment: What if the columns aren't identical?  Like if table1 had an extra column?

Comment: Then you would have to specify the columns: `INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3) SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 From Table2 .....`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  In fact it answered a question that I had posted earlier today without any full outer joins .

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.*,B.* from TABLE1 AS A,TABLE2 AS B where A.code=B.code GROUP BY A.code;
```

I think you are talking about TABLE not DATABASE. Use `GROUP BY` clause or find `DISTINCT` value with the query. And you have not specified any primary key..so read mysql tutorial first..

Comment: Thanks but how can I delete one of the rows who are the same?

Comment: Delete from Table2 where code in (select code from Table1);
you can compare with code or name or number, which may be posible of redundent